# Is there a way to check the number of confirmations in a Blockchain hash? And check when the transaction is fully confirmed?

Tags: python, blockchain, bitcoin

I’ve been trying to look for a way to get the number of confirmations in a certain blockchain hash, but have gotten nowhere.

I’m basically trying to find a way to print when the said transaction becomes 4/4.

Could anyone please give me a starting guide? Thanks!

Edit:

I’ve tried things like `https://blockchain.info/rawtx/$tx_hash` using requests, I still cannot find a way to get the amount of confirmations and wait til it hits 4.

Comment: What did you try? What are you using? Have you got a snippet of your code? Can you explain the problem in detail?

Comment: The page you linked on `blockchain.info` isn't a real page, can you provide an actual link and the snippet of your requests code. Also have you tried BeautifulSoup?

Comment: `getrawtransaction` rpc call gives `confirmations`. Check it out here https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/getrawtransaction.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method to get transaction confirmations by using `getrawtransaction` rpc method with verbose flag set to `true`. Part of the json output looks like:

```json
  "blockhash" : "hex",               (string) the block hash
  "confirmations" : n,               (numeric) The confirmations
  "blocktime" : xxx,                 (numeric) The block time expressed in UNIX epoch time
  "time" : n                         (numeric) Same as "blocktime"
```

The full docs how to use it is [here](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/getrawtransaction.html)